# Чем отличаются методы в pathlib: Path.rename от Path.replace

Tags: python, файловая-система, pathlib

Оба метода одинаково переименовывают файл.
По документации разница не ясна.
Методом тыка разница тоже не обнаружена.

Comment: https://bugs.python.org/issue27886

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Две версии практически одинаковых методов существуют по исторической причине, причем
`Path.rename()` и `Path.replace()` повторяют методы `os.rename()` и `os.replace()`.

---

- `.rename()`: в случае существования такой папки или файла результат зависит от операционной системы:

  - Windows: ошибка `OSError`.
  - POSIX системы: переименование, и за счет потери (замены в случае существования).

  Возвращает

  - `None` для версий Питона перед 3.8
  - новый объект `Path` для версий 3.8+.

---

- `.replace()`: всегда переименование, и за счет потери (замены в случае существования).

  Возвращает

  - `None` для версий Питона перед 3.8
  - новый объект `Path` для версий 3.8+.

---

Значит, лучше использовать `.replace()`, потому что он не зависит от операционной системы (и перед применением проверить, если папка или файл с таким именем уже не существует).

Comment: У меня на Windows-10 .rename() спокойно переименовывает и файлы и директории, не задавая никаких вопросов. Python 3.9.1

Поэтому и был задан этот вопрос.

Comment: @Voko, разница только тогда, когда папка или файл с таким именем *уже существует.*

Answer (score 0):

Помогла ссылка из первого комментария.

**Path.rename()** гарантированно переименовывает существующий файл только в Unix.

**Path.replace** является кросплатформенным и переименовывает независимо от платформы.